# AngularJS keep adding item in a scope

Tags: angularjs

I made a dummy data for my application using this method in my controller:

```
$scope.owners = [];

        for (var i = 1; i <= 14; i++) {
            $scope.owners.push({
                id: i,
                systemCode: '00' + (1284538+i),
                systemName: 'Desktop',
                description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor',
                operational: '2973238',
                business: '5621253',
                manager: 'Dr. Smith',
                status: 'Active'
            });
        }
```

and adding this function to perform delete request:

```
$scope.rowDelete = function(row){
            $scope.owners.splice((this.owner.id - 1), 1);
        }
```

and a page filter to use for pagination:

```
MyApp.filter('page', function () {
    return function (list, page, size) {
        var start = 0, end = 0;

        //console.log('page filter...', page, size);
        page = page || 1;

        if (angular.isArray(list)) {
            end = list.length;

            if (page && Number(page) && size && Number(size)) {
                page = Number(page);
                size = Number(size);

                start = (page - 1) * size;
                end = start + size;
            }

            return Array.prototype.slice.call(list, start, end);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

});

In the HTML template, I'm using ng-repeat and the custom filter:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="owner in owners | page:$stateParams.page:2">
<td class="table-cell-clean">
    <a href="javascript:;" data-ng-click="rowDelete()" class="btn btn-clean"><i class="mg-icon-delete"></i></a>
</td>
<td>{{ owner.systemCode }}</td>
<td>{{ owner.systemName }}</td>
<td>{{ owner.description }}</td>
<td>{{ owner.operational }}</td>
<td>{{ owner.business }}</td>
<td>{{ owner.manager }}</td>
<td class="align-center">{{ owner.status }}</td>
```

Whenever I click the delete button, rowDelete() is called as expected, the row is deleted, but as soon as it's leaving the DOM, a new item from the next page is inserted into the current table.

What might go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be as expected.  Your owners array is being modified which requires the ng-repeat expression to be re-evaluated which includes the page filter expression as apart of it.  So owners is modified by deleting a row, ng-repeat detects the change and re-evaluates the repeat expression which before it can iterate over the array it runs owners through the page filter.  So n items per page, delete leaves n-1, and page filters the owners array to return n items.

All normal behavior.

Comment: Any idea how to prevent the default behavior (i.e.: reevaluating the expression)?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  You can signify what's happening with animation to help the user understand what's going on.  The only other option is using bind once directives that people have written.  Generally without using Angularjs 1.3.x or using specialized code no there is no way to prevent it.